# How do I install Prismic.io tool on an existing Nuxt.js project

Tags: nuxt.js, prismic.io, nuxt-i18n

I have been trying to install Prismic.io tool on my existing Nuxt.js project:

I have upgraded nuxt first:

```
npm upgrade nuxt
```

I have installed prismic via npm:

```
npm i @nuxtjs/prismic
```

In `package.json` file, the dependencies are now the following:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
  "@nuxtjs/prismic": "^1.3.1",
  "core-js": "^3.9.1",
  "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
  "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
  "nuxt-i18n": "^6.27.1",
  "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
}
```

I have created `link-resolver.js` and `html-serializer.js` files in the `plugins` folder:

**link-resolver.js :**

```js
export default function (doc) {
    return '/'
}
```

**html-serializer :**

```js
export default function (doc) {
    return '/'
}
```

then, I have added the needed modules in `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
modules: [
  'nuxt-i18n',
  '@nuxtjs/prismic'
],
prismic: {
  endpoint: 'https://prismicrepository.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2',
  linkResolver: '~/plugins/link-resolver',
  htmlSerializer: '~/plugins/html-serializer',
}
```

Then I have run

```
npm install
```

And after all of these steps, my project still acting as there is no prismic tool installed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://prismic.nuxtjs.org/installation), it looks like you need to:

`npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/prismic`, then make some configuration in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
{
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/prismic'
  ],
  prismic: {
    // don't forget to update "REPOSITORY" here
    endpoint: 'https://<REPOSITORY>.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2',
    modern: true
  }
}
```

You've already written the resolver. Also, you don't need to `npm install` at the end because it already does when installing your NPM packages.
After that, everything should be working.